Сравнительный оборот или придаточное сравнения?

Я свободен, словно птица в небесах

Обстоятельство "в небесах" должно по идее относиться к пропущенному сказуемому "свободен", но, с другой стороны, структура сочетания птица (какая) в небесах (то есть небесная) представляется мне тоже возможной. А это говорит о том, что "в небесах" будет не обстоятельством, а несогласованным определением. Если данное сочетание будет несогласованным определением, то слова-помощника для придаточного сравнения уже здесь не будет, а это значит, что перед нами находится сравнительный оборот, так?

Это сравнительный оборот: Я свободен, словно птица в небесах.
ТЕОРИЯ

Между сравнительным оборотом СО и сравнительным придаточным предложением существует значительная разница. Придаточное — это предикативная конструкция, имеющая  грамматическую основу, а СО — полупредикативная.

Одно из определений сравнительного оборота:  Сравнительный оборот — это часть простого предложения, выражающая сравнение одного объекта с другим на основе общего признака.


Также другое определение: Сравнительный оборот — это распространённый стилистический приём, заключающийся в сопоставлении двух объектов или явлений.

О грамматическое значении СПП с придаточным сравнительным (из учебника по синтаксису Кустовой):

Ситуация главной части характеризуется характеризуется через установление сходства, подобия, частичного тождества с ситуацией придаточной части.

Принципиальная разница в том, что в СО сравниваются объекты или явления, а в СПП сравниваются ситуации. Если придаточное неполное, то возникают трудности при решении конкретных задач.

Также стоит обратить внимание на союзы. Союз КАК является  основным союзом, в то время как союзы СЛОВНО, БУДТО и др. имеют ограниченное применение и чаще используются в художественных целях.


РЕШЕНИЕ
(1) Я свободен, словно птица в небесах. Это сравнительный оборот, где в небесах — обстоятельственное определение. То есть сравниваются объекты — я и птица.
Сравнить: свободен как птица в полете (устойчивое сочетание).
(2) Я в своей жизни свободен, как птица (свободна) в небесах.
Это СПП с неполным придаточным сравнительным, так как сравниваются ситуации. О пропуске сказуемого говорит наличие одинакового падежного управления: свободен  в жизни и свободен в небесах.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (неполные сравнительные придаточные)
В неполных придаточных предложениях можно восстановить пропущенный член предложения по смыслу:
(1) Пропущено подлежащее
Мы втроём начали беседовать, как будто (мы) век были 
знакомы.
Умное животное следило за нами, точно (оно) хотело узнать, 
что мы намерены делать.
Лес стоит молча, словно (он) всматривается куда-то своими 
верхушками и ждёт чего-то.

(2) Пропущено сказуемое
Гостиная набита гостями, как подушка (набита) пером.
Дни отрываются от меня, как листики (отрываются) от дерева.

Статья по теме: Сравнительный оборот

Так как в итоге решить однозначно?

Нужно обозначить ситуацию, как в этом предложении, так чтобы подразумевалось только пропущенное сказуемое, тогда будет однозначность:  Я в своей жизни свободен, как птица (свободна) в небесах.  Добавлено обстоятельство, и уже сравниваются ситуации. А иначе будет оборот.
